# python selenium get asp-classic element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, asp-classic, automated-tests

I tried find this URL page to do some selenium automation test, usually can get web element but some page is strange...i can not find the web element even using XPATH (use chrome browser can see the element, But can not do some action for this element..in fact...wrong message is "can not find the element)

looks like is asp.classic generate page....windows.onload() page

```
driver_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = webdriver.Ie(driver_path)
driver.get(mytestpage)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Hardware")))
element.click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "'//*[@id="testpage"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/font/a[1]'")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with selenium explicit wait? This might be because a page is getting loaded fully while you are performing selenium action on that page. Also, check response time for loading page.